# writing SAS code to import .kmf files

Tags: sas

I am trying to figure out how to import .kmf files (keyboard macro files) using code in SAS. I have been doing research and have found nothing on the topic. I need to be able to manage updates to several .kmf files across several computers accross several servers. So, doing the usual import is not efficient enough for my needs. Is this even possible in the SAS envoriment? If so where can I find information to help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to SAS documents located at http://support.sas.com/kb/19/335.html

> The SAS Enhanced Editor allows you to create keyboard macros and
>   keyboard abbreviations.
>
> - **To create keyboard macros select Tools >Keyboards Macros.**
> - **To create keyboard abbreviations select Tools > Add Abbreviation**.
>
> You also have the functionality to export these to a
>   file and then import them into SAS on another machine.
>
> - Note that in order to avoid overwriting any existing keyboard short cut keys, the
>     key assignments for Keyboard Macros are not exported. You need to
>     reassign the keys after importing. The Abbreviations do not have key
>     assignments. To accomplish this do the following: Click Tools >
>     Keyboard Macros > Macros Hold down the SHIFT key or CTRL key and
>     left-click to select the abbreviations and macros to export Click on
>     the EXPORT button and save to a file with the extension .kmf Copy the
>     file to another machine. Open SAS on the other machine. Click Tools >
>     Keyboard Macros > Macros. Click the import buttton and select the .kmf
>     file. For keyboard macros only, click Assign keys and choose a new
>     shortcut key for each macro.

---

There is also a SAS Global forum paper that discusses the issues. The specific way to do what you asked for is pasted below. Refer to the entire paper at this link... (http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/073-2009.pdf) for details on the steps using both the editor or EG.

---

> SHARING YOUR ABBREVIATIONS 
>   You might want to share your abbreviations with others, or perhaps you will need to put your >abbreviations on a different computer. This is very easy to do!
>
> EXPORTING ABBREVIATIONS 
>   Place the cursor in the Enhanced Editor window. 
>   Select the Tools menu and then Keyboard Macros, followed by Macros.
>
> A window opens where you select the abbreviations to export.
>
> • If you want to select more than one, hold down the CTRL key on your keyboard as you click on each abbreviation.
>
> • If you would like all of them, click on the first abbreviation in the list, hold down the Shift key, and click on the 
>   last abbreviation. They should all be highlighted. Click on the export button.